# How to whitelist WpnUserService through firewall if it keeps changing it's service name

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-11, windows-firewall

I am using [WFC Firewall](https://www.binisoft.org/wfc), which is a wrapper on the native Windows Firewall.

Every time I restart my PC, WpnUserService changes its name. Basically, the 6-digit alpha-numeric suffix on the service name changes and my previous rules become invalid (The screenshot doesn't show them as invalid, but they are actually right now since the Service name is changed).

How do I firewall it? Is it possible to disable the 6-digit suffix so the service name always remains the same?

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

.

Comment: Bump...........

Comment: Bump...........